# Use twig variables into ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twig

i have a personal mvc architecture and i want to use variables passed from the controller to the twig template into an included js file.

There are my files, All about the variable $server_ID :

**DashboardController.php** who send the $server_ID variable to the template

```
class DashboardController extends Controller {

    public function get($id = null) {
        $serverModel = $this->model('ServerModel');
        $server_ID = $serverModel->findById($id);
        $this->view('dashboard/get', ['server_ID' => $server_ID]);
    }
    public function ajax_getstats($server_ID) {
        $return = ServerModel::getStats($server_ID);
        echo json_encode($return);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Twig template **main.html** that make the layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        {% include 'head.html' %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% include 'header.html' %}
            <div class="content">
                {% block content %}{% endblock %}
            </div>
        {% include 'scripts.html' %}
    </body>
</html>
```

**scripts.html** that include specific js files

```
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<script src="{{ ASSET_ROOT }}/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ ASSET_ROOT }}/assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="{{ ASSET_ROOT }}/assets/js/dashboard.js"></script>
```

And finaly **dashboard.js** where what i want to use the variable $server_ID

```
function getStats() {
    var rStart = Date.now();
    $.getJSON("http://localhost/site/public/dashboard/ajax_getstats/" + {{ server_ID }}, function(data)
    {
       // treatment here
 });
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    getStats();
});
```

Comment: Hello and welcome! Congratulations on your first question. It's best if you also include the error you are getting. That would help your question and those who want to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hidden input type in the **main.html** page which contains the value of `server_ID`, and then grab it in the JavaScript file.

**main.html:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        {% include 'head.html' %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="hidden" id="server-id" value="{{ server_ID }}"> <!-- This echos the server_ID variable to become the value for this input. -->
        {% include 'header.html' %}
            <div class="content">
                {% block content %}{% endblock %}
            </div>
        {% include 'scripts.html' %}
    </body>
</html>
```

**dashboard.js:**

```js
let serverID = $("#server-id").val(); // This variable is now equal to $server_ID.

function getStats() {
    var rStart = Date.now();
    $.getJSON("http://localhost/site/public/dashboard/ajax_getstats/" + {{ server_ID }}, function(data)
    {
       // treatment here
 });
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    getStats();
});
```

Comment: It is a good idea but i want something more dynamic because i don't want include the dashboard.js in others views !!

Comment: what u mean? The suggested solution doesn't require you to include anything

Comment: If you don't want to include that file every time, you could just have inline JS?

`<script>let serverID = $("#server-id").val();</script>
`